# Stack Overflow pages became primitive after sudden slow server-response

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was browsing around in Stack Overflow and suddenly it didn't work anymore and eventually I got this message:

[image]

Then I went off to edit someone's question, but since a suggested edit was still pending I couldn't do that. But instead of seeing the normal page, I saw this:

[image]

I found this pretty odd, so I thought I'd report it here.

Comment: Note that the first picture is not my screenshot. I am not Benjamin Gruenbaum. I simply found it by searching on Google.

Comment: It's already fixed as it seems.

Comment: You probably caught things mid deploy.

Answer (score 6):

We apologize for the fault in the CSS. [Those responsible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277543/who-is-this-engineer) have been sacked. <sup>[[x](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZJC5ORod7I?t=2m6s)]</sup>

Comment: It just happened again this very moment. Who is responsible now?